# How can the action at the form get the value?

Tags: php, html, forms

When I try to use this structure:

```
<form name="confirm" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="confirm_sent.php?name=<?PHP echo $name; ?>">
...........//sth doing at here
<input type="submit" class="popUpButton" name="confirmButton" id="submitPage4" value="Confirm" />
```

The name was get from the URL:

```
http://localhost/reserve/app/confirm.php?name=$name
```

But, when I click the button `confirmButton` it will directly to confirm_sent.php
but at the URL there the value of name does not show out only show this:

```
http://localhost/reserve/app/confirm_sent.php?confirmButton=Confirm
```

So, I would like to ask that it is my concept wrong or did I do it the wrong way?

Thanks for the help / advice... :)

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: You can't use `multipart/form-data` with `GET` requests, only `POST`.

Comment: @Barmar means that I need to change to POST
if I change to POST the value of name cannot GET right?

Comment: URL parameters are always in `$_GET`, even when you use `POST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `method="GET"`, you can't put parameters in the `action` URL. You should use a hidden input field instead:

```
<form name="confirm" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" action="confirm_sent.php">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="?PHP echo $name; ?>">
```

But if you need to use `multipart/form-data`, because you have a file input, you can't use `method="GET"`, you have to use `method="POST"`. In that case, you can either have the parameter in the URL or in a hidden field.

```
<form name="confirm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="confirm_sent.php?name=<?PHP echo $name; ?>">
```

The `name` parameter will be in `$_GET['name']`, all the other inputs will be in `$_POST` (except the file inputs will be in `$_FILES`).